# Mistakenly approved suggested edit

Tags: support, status-completed, editing, specific-question

By mistake, I approved the edit to [erroneous decisions by beit din for which korbanot must be brought by beit din and the people](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69575/3073), when I wanted to improve the edit. The edit's last sentence changes the meaning of the question. It should read: "Do we know of such a mistake that was made by a beit din? If so, what was it?"

No I cannot edit the question again to fix my mistake, because my approval is on hold awaiting further approval.

How do I un-mess this mess?

Comment: Wait for approval/rejection and then edit?

Comment: I see an edit from you now; were you able to make the change you wanted?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yes, thanks. Can you [tag:status-completed] this?